# Cannot find server name

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2014 Standard. In the Data Tools in 2013 with the connection setup I do not see any server names. When calling `sqlcmd -L` all servers are visible. In SQL Server Configuration Manager Network Configuration I set the TCP / IP, Shared Memory and Named Pipes have set enabled.

I installed all the server components.

Comment: SQL Server uses the string `(local)` instead of `localhost` if you're connecting to loopback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Start Menu > Microsoft SQL Server 2014 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager` and then look at the screen you're seeing:

[image]

Unter `SQL Server Services`, there ought to be at least one entry `SQL Server` with the **instance name** in parenthesis.

If the instance name is `MSSQLSERVER`, you have a **default**, un-named instance to which you can connect using `.`, `(local)` or `machine-name` as the server/instance name.

If the instance is anything else, using `.\INSTANCE`, `(local)\INSTANCE` or `machine-name\INSTANCE` as your server/instance name to connect to.